# ArrayList cannot be applied - Android

Tags: android, arraylist, adapter

LazyAdapter (android.app.Activity, ArrayList>) in LazyAdapter cannot be applied to (com.example.app.CustomizedListView, ArrayList>)

Can I have some input on how to fix this error or what needs to be changed to fix it. I am not sure what other files you may need but I have no clue as to what is wrong. Thanks for reading.

CustomizedListView.class:

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Fragment {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.game_list);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }




    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
}
}
```

LazyAdapter.class:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this

```
   adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
```

by

```
   adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
```

You should use `getActivity()` which will get you the activity context of the activity hosting the fragment.

Specifically, the `fragment` can access the `Activity instance` with `getActivity()`.

`public final Activity getActivity ()`

Added in API level 11

**Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.**

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it. I forgot to use getActivity.